Publish ASP.NET MVC project without using PublishProfile
I want to publish my ASP.NET MVC project through command prompt using msbuild.
When I use the publishProfile, it works fine and generates the publish folder at the desired location; but when I use commands instead of the publishProfile, it doesn't generate the publish folder.
This is the publish profile :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>D:\Published</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

When I use this command, it works fine and generates the output at D:\Published (as mentioned in PublishProfile)
msbuild "D:\secureamr_ss_premier_500_branch\source\WebSite\SecureAMRWeb.sln" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="D:\secureamr_ss_premier_500_branch\source\WebSite\SecureAMRWeb\Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml"

But when I use this command (in this command I remove the publishProfile instead I include all properties of publishProfiles in msbuild command), it didn't generate any results at D:\Published (as specified in the command)
msbuild "D:\secureamr_ss_premier_500_branch\source\WebSite\SecureAMRWeb.sln" /p:DeployOnBuild=true 
/p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem 
/p:PublishProvider=FileSystem 
/p:publishUrl="D:\Published" 
/p:LastUsedBuildConfiguration=Release 
/p:LastUsedPlatform="Any CPU" 
/p:LaunchSiteAfterPublish=True 
/p:ExcludeApp_Data=False 
/p:DeleteExistingFiles=True


You can take a look at my answer. :)

I am able to reproduce your issue.
First, according to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/building-clickonce-applications-from-the-command-line?view=vs-2022#publish-process- output), PublishUrl as command property cannot be used in commands before VS 2022 17.4.
Also, although the information you gave is not entirely clear, I think you are using a .net framework web app, right? In fact, this problem occurs not only in web apps, but also in projects based on .net framework. .net framework is a very old framework. If you want to use a property such as PublishUrl, you need to base it on a file such as pubxml, otherwise the incoming command part will not be recognized.
For .NET framework this command will work:
msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true 
        /p:PublishProfile=xxx\FolderProfile.pubxml

But command like this will not work, the property will not be recognized:
msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true 
        /p:PublishUrl='C:\Published'

If you try it, you will find that .NET Core apps can use the second command.
